# issue in specifying attribute name while eagerLoading in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, eager-loading

I have a model and doing eager Loading in using findAll().
The issue is when I use sequelize.col("ColName"), it only works in first level of include.
But it gives an error *ERROR Invalid column name  'exerciseLocation.name* when I use it in the depper level JOIN (I've already added alias in the associations)

> sequelize version : 6.14.1

Here is my code

```
Scheduler.findAll({
      where: { userId: _userId },
      attributes: [
        "id",
        "title",
        [db.sequelize.col("Location.name"), "location"], // This works fine
      ],
      include: [
        {
          model: Locations,
          attributes: [],
        },
        {
          model: ExerciseList, 
attributes: [
        "id",
        "title",
        [db.sequelize.col("exerciseLocation.name"), "location"],  /* ERROR Invalid column name 'exerciseLocation.name'*/
      ],
          include: [
            {
              model: Locations,
              attributes: [],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    })
```

My associations

```
db.Scheduler.belongsTo(db.Locations, {foreignKey: "location",});
db.Scheduler.hasMany(db.ExerciseList, {foreignKey: "SchedulerId",});

db.ExerciseList.belongsTo(db.Scheduler, {foreignKey: "SchedulerId",});
db.ExerciseList.belongsTo(db.Exercises, {foreignKey: "exerciseId",});

db.ExerciseList.belongsTo(db.Locations, {foreignKey: "locationId", as: 'exerciseLocation'});
```

Comment: Add all association definitions for all mentioned models

Comment: added. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: You have `Locations` on two levels. Looks at the generated SQL to see aliases for both Location models

Comment: Scheduler and ExerciseList both are associated with Locations

Comment: It's ok, just look at aliases and use a proper one in Sequelize.col

Comment: added alias.
but still it the issue persists. 
I have looked at the generated SQL 
``` [ExcerciseLists].[exerciseLocation.name] -- this gives error ``` and found that if I replace the query with ``` [ExcerciseLists->exerciseLocation].[name] ``` Then the query works on SQL server.
I figured out that it does not has to do with the Locations model being associated  twice instead issue still persists even if a different association is called on the 2nd LEVEL OF ASSOCIATION

Comment: I see that you didn't indicate `exerciseLocation` in `as` option of `include`